# DELETE FROM query of php not working without any error, and leaving on same page

Tags: php, html, database

I am unable to delete my data from a database through PHP code, though I can from phpmyadmin. 
I have attached both of my PHP and HTML. I tried to use the same code which is used by phpmyadmin, but there is no progress. Even with this, I am not getting alert message which I use to debug and there is no outcome.

```js
<?php
    $conn2=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysqli_Select_db($conn2,"editor") or die("connot connect to the database");

    if (isset ($_GET ['delid'] ) ) {
        $deluser=$_GET['delid'];

        $alertMessage = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
        <p> Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p><br>
        <form action='".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']). " ?id=$deluser' method='post'>
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' id='con_del' name='con_del' value='Yes' delete!>
            <a href='location.. /listNB.php' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>X</a>
        </form>
        </div>
        ";
    }

    if (isset($_GET['con_del']))
    {
        $entry_id= $row["entry_id"];
        $sql= "DELETE FROM `editornb` WHERE `editornb`.`entry_id` = '".$entry_id."'";
        $que= mysqli_query($conn2,$sql);
             
        if ($que) {
            print'<script> alert("Sucessfully deleted!!!");</script>';
            
        } else{
            print'<script> alert("error");</script>';
            
        }

    }

?>
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> CK EDITOR </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome/fontawesome-free-5.0.6/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if (isset($alertMessage))
     echo $alertMessage;

    ?>
    <br> 
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="textareaNB.php"> Home </a>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="ListNB.php">List</a>
    <br><br>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th> ID</th>
            <th> DATE</th>
            <th> Content</th>
            <th> Update</th> 
            <th> Delete</th>

        </tr>
        <?php
        session_start();
        $user=($_SESSION['u_uid']);
        $query="SELECT * FROM `editornb` where user_uid='".$user."'";
        $result= mysqli_query($conn2, $query);
        $result_check= mysqli_num_rows ($result);
        $date=date("M/d/y");
        if ( $result_check > 0 )
        {
         while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" .$row["entry_id"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row["date"]. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row["content"]."</td>";
                echo '<td><a href="update.php?upid='.$row['entry_id'].'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> 
                <span class="fa fa-edit"></span> </a></td>';

                echo '<td><a href="ListNB.php?delid='.$row['entry_id'].'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> </a></td>';

                echo"</tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>

    </table>
</booy>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have error handling on? Have you wrapped your code in exception handling? Do you use an IDE with a debugger and step through it, a line at a time? Any/all of those would mean that you did not have to ask us that question

Answer (score 1):

OKay guys i found the solution of my own question...
what is did was i tried to fetch the emtry number which i was trying to delete.
by using the same query that i did for fetching the data for my table.
whcih is select * from tablename.

than using mysqli_fetch_assoc i retrived my data used the $row varibale.
 i works just fine for my program, hope it helps someone,

though i did used @KarloKokkak's and @prasannaputtaswamy suggestion

```js
 if (isset($_POST['del']))
   {   
        $user=($_SESSION['u_uid']);
        $query="SELECT * FROM `editornb` where user_uid='".$user."'";
        $result= mysqli_query($conn2, $query);
        $result_check= mysqli_num_rows ($result);
        $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $id =($row['entry_id']);
        $user=($_SESSION['u_uid']);
        $sql= "DELETE FROM editornb WHERE user_uid='$user' AND entry_id= '$id' ";
        $answer= mysqli_query($conn2,$sql);
        if ($answer == TRUE ) {
         print'<script> alert("Sucessfully deleted!!!");</script>';
        } else{
         print'<script> alert("error");</script>';
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_Select_db` typo ?

**should be:**
`mysqli_select_db`

Remove `htmlspecialchars()` in `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`

**Just do**

```
 $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

You are assigning `$entry_id` the wrong value;

**From:**

```
$entry_id= $row["entry_id"];
```

**To:**

```
$entry_id= $_GET["id"];
```

**In your second PHP file:**
Remove the existing `session_start();` and move it at the very top of that file. You can't output anything before sending headers. It will cause error.

```
<?php session_start(); ?> <-- Move it there like that. No whitespace before "<?php"
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> CK EDITOR </title>
```

Also you have an extra space character in your `<form>` action attribute. In your `<form>` tag, the `action=""` attribute, **Change:**

```
" ?id=$deluser'
```

To:

```
"?id=$deluser'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but still, this tricks is not working either.

Comment: I had a typo. Make $entry_id= $_POST["id"]; to $entry_id= $_GET["id"];

Comment: Added another fix. Check the additional change at the bottom.

Comment: do you think that my delete query has any fault? if i am calling the entry_id wrong. as "entry_id is my column's name in the database and and I'm calling $row["entry_id"] in the table but when i am deleting it I am calling entry_id which my code seems to not find because its a part of my database?

Answer (score 0):

After making all changes as suggested by @Karlo Kokkak change

```
$entry_id= $_POST["id"];
```

To

```
$entry_id= $_POST["con_del"];
```

That should work fine. If you echo the query check if correct id is passing to it or not.